# How Object.defineProperty getters and setters for all unknown children in object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

for example, I define an object `obj`:

```
var obj = {}
Object.defineProperty(obj, "a", {
  value : 37,
  writable : true,
  enumerable : true,
  configurable : true
});
console.log(obj.a); // => 37
```

I want to access all unknown children getter same value, like `obj.a.b.c.d.e` / `obj.c.d.e.f.e....`  => 37

Comment: If `obj.a` is to be 37, then `obj.a.b` is going to be `37.b` which is undefined...

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to return a *number* like that, because every nested property *must* return an object if you want to be able to access indefinitely further nested keys - the best you can do is return an object which can be coerced to a desired string, probably with a Proxy:

```js
const handler = {
  get(_, prop) {
    return prop === Symbol['toPrimitive']
    ? () => '37'
    : objProx;
  }
}
const objProx = new Proxy({}, handler);

console.log('' + objProx.a); // => '37'
console.log('' + objProx.a.b); // => '37'
console.log('' + objProx.a.b.c.d.e.foobarbaz); // => '37'
```

Answer (score 2):

You could create a function which takes in another function as a parameter. And execute the function within a `try...catch` and return the value if it exists or return a default value if there is an error:

```js
const DEFAULT_VAL = 37;

// get a function and an optional default value to override
function getAnyDepth(func, def) {
    try {
        return func();
    } catch (e) {
        return typeof def !== "undefined" ? def : DEFAULT_VAL;
    }
}

var obj = { a: 45 }

console.log(getAnyDepth(() => obj.a))
console.log(getAnyDepth(() => obj.a.b.c.d.e))
console.log(getAnyDepth(() => obj.c.d.e, { b: 100 }))
```

[Reference: How to avoid "Cannot read property 'name' of undefined" in JavaScript](https://silvantroxler.ch/2017/avoid-cannot-read-property-of-undefined/)

Answer (score 1):

If you mean you want a default value each time you access an undefined key in your object you an do :

```
_.defaults(obj, {value: 37"})
```

or you can go with the standard comparison :

```
if(typeof obj.a =='undefined'){
  return 37
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If `obj.a` is to equal 37, then `obj.a.b` would evaluate to `37.b` which is undefined. However, if you would be OK if 37 would be the result of turning something to a primitive (e.g. by string concatenation), then you could create a proxy.

Demo:

```js
// Preparation
function setDefaultProperty(obj, defProp) {
    return new Proxy(obj, {
        get(target, prop) {
            if (prop in target || typeof prop === "symbol") return target[prop];
            return target[defProp];
        }
    });
}

var sink = setDefaultProperty({}, "_default");
sink._default = sink;
sink.valueOf = () => 37;

// Demo

var obj = {};

obj = setDefaultProperty(obj, "_default");
obj._default = sink;

console.log("" + obj.a.b.c.e); // 37
console.log("" + obj.what.ever); // 37
```